# Where is Sickbay on the Enterpise(s)

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

If you know or have links to diagrams, I'd be interested knowing the answer to where on various Enterprises Sickbay is located. I've found some maps on the internet, but they focus on Engineering and kind of lame portrays of crew quarters, not where sickbay is. I would like to know where it is at least in terms of Primary or Secondary hull. Also not just TNG: bloody A...B..C....and D. Thanks if you can help!

Comment: @JamesSheridan - Google **"Handera"**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Each starship would have the medical quarters in slightly differing locations depending on design and technology requirements.

- For the most part, given the need for defense and protection, medical facilities are located in the central region of the ship protected by the ventral and dorsal shields and multiple deck layers.
- On larger ships, there are often multiple sickbay facilities both in the primary hull and the secondary hull. There are also medical surgical and support facilities located through out the ship.

#### Enterprise NX-01

**Medical is amidships likely one of the most protected regions of the ship in terms of shields and armor.**

> - The NX-class had a single sickbay ward on E Deck. The room contained a main operating table, as well as several side beds for recovery of patients and an imaging chamber. It was also easily capable of caring for non-humanoid patients.
> - The facility was open-plan, with laboratory equipment in the main sickbay area. Aboard Enterprise NX-01, Dr. Phlox often kept various different species of animals in sickbay, which he would sometimes use in the treatment of injuries in lieu of more traditional treatments. One such animal was an osmotic eel. (ENT: "These Are the Voyages...", "Fight or Flight", "A Night in Sickbay", "Broken Bow")

[image]

#### USS Enterprise 1701 (Constitution Class Cruiser, unrefit)

> - Due to its critical importance, the primary sickbay was usually located deep within the saucer section of most Federation starships.
> - On Constitution-class starships, sickbay was located on Deck 7. (In TOS: "Mirror, Mirror" it was located on Deck 5.) It was maintained and operated by the Astro-Medicine Department. There were at least four wards. (TOS: "The Naked Time") In addition to this ward, there was an isolation ward. (TOS: "Turnabout Intruder")

[image]

*Click [here](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-zcLQXWG5hiA/Uad8qIYjJlI/AAAAAAAAR6o/TA01Sv94pqI/s1600/Star+Trek+Enterprise+In+a+Mirror+Darkly+Constitution+class+cross+section.jpg) for much larger image.*

#### USS Enterprise, NCC 1710-D (Galaxy Class Cruiser)

[image]

*No official diagrams held a confirmed configuration of the deckplans of the Enterprise D placing the primary medical facility. Its location on this non-offical image corresponds with text entries and previous specifications for medical facilities. Official blueprint schematics list only military offensive and defensive assets. A larger look at this [blueprint](http://lcarsgfx.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/galaxy_mk2_engineering_01-copy.png) can be found at the link.*

> - Due to its critical importance, the primary sickbay was usually located deep within the saucer section of most Federation starships. Sickbays were well-protected, and generally had a phaser locker for defense of the facility in the event the ship was boarded. (TNG: "Starship Mine", "Timescape")
> - Galaxy-class ships had at least three sickbay wards. (TNG: "Tapestry") Two sickbay wards were located on Deck 12 of the saucer module, with the primary facility on the starboard side of the ship and a backup on the port. (TNG: "A Matter of Perspective") Another sickbay was in the stardrive section. (TNG: "The Arsenal of Freedom"; Star Trek Generations)
> - Galaxy-class ships had one of the largest medical care facilities in the fleet, taking up the majority of Deck 12. In an alternate timeline, Captain Rachel Garrett marveled at the size and advancement of the Enterprise-D sickbay, stating that she had "never seen anything like it before, even on a starbase." (TNG: "Yesterday's Enterprise", "Remember Me")
> - Galaxy-class ships normally had several doctors on board and at least four medical personnel on duty at all times. (TNG: "Remember Me", "Genesis")

**REF: [Memory Alpha, Sickbay](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sickbay)**

Comment: Note that in TNG we only ever a small part of sick bay - usually just the ICU near Dr. Crusher's office. The entire facility takes up [more than half of the front of deck 12](https://forgottentrek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Enterprise-D-sickbay-deck-plan.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the schematics here" http://www.waxingmoondesign.com/DeckEPage.html
There's also another site with blueprints: http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/blueprints-main2.php

Comment: Welcome to SFF. We try to avoid link only answers. If you find a picture on a website the best thing to do is to add that picture to your answer and give credit to the source. This helps us avoid problems if links go dead. As you can the accepted answer has done.